# Fedora 24 + OpenAFS - Service Failing to Start after Reboot

Tags: linux, fedora

I followed this guide [here](https://gist.github.com/danifr/773d7b049454390d1e51) on how to install OpenAFS - however I haven't managed to get it working.

The problem I am facing at the moment is after I reboot, if I run the command

```
sudo systemctl status openafs-client.service
```

I see the following output:

```
● openafs-client.service - OpenAFS Client Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openafs-client.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-12-18 14:43:56 GMT; 25min ago

Dec 18 14:43:55 ppdhcp45.hep.manchester.ac.uk systemd[1]: Starting OpenAFS Client Service...
Dec 18 14:43:56 ppdhcp45.hep.manchester.ac.uk modprobe[956]: modprobe: FATAL: Module openafs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.13-200.fc24.x86_64
Dec 18 14:43:56 ppdhcp45.hep.manchester.ac.uk systemd[1]: openafs-client.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 18 14:43:56 ppdhcp45.hep.manchester.ac.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenAFS Client Service.
Dec 18 14:43:56 ppdhcp45.hep.manchester.ac.uk systemd[1]: openafs-client.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 18 14:43:56 ppdhcp45.hep.manchester.ac.uk systemd[1]: openafs-client.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 18 15:02:27 ppdhcp45.hep.manchester.ac.uk systemd[1]: Stopped OpenAFS Client Service.
```

I am kind of new to Fedora, but have used Ubuntu for a number of years. Could anyone give me any pointers on how to go about diagnozing and fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The wording of theerror message is quite clear:

> modprobe: FATAL: Module openafs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.13-200.fc24.x86_64

Your OpenAFS needs a kernel module of the same name and modules are loaded from the above directory. It very depends on how you installed your package, but what happened is that you got a new kernel version and openAFS kernel module was probably installed only for the old kernel module.

You would probably need to rebuild/reinstall your OpenAFS package.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to extend [Jakuje's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1157867/298570) with my solution.

> You would probably need to rebuild/reinstall your OpenAFS ...

was tricky for me. Ubuntu do have `openafs-client` in its repos, but module was still not found. So I installed module assistant:

```
$ sudo apt-get install module-assistant
```

and then

```
$ sudo module-assistant auto-install openafs
```

[credits](https://bobcares.com/blog/openafs-with-ubuntu-installation-howto/)